# Uploading A Base64 encode Image to php server

Tags: php, android, base64

how do i upload a Base64 encoded image to a PHP server using `HttpURLConnection?` All the answers i have seen so far are based on `HttpClient` which no longer exists. I got a `httprequest.java` library that sends post request to the server, the problem i have with it is that the image string at the server-side is always different to the one i send.

This is my code so far.

```
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(Konstants.address+Konstants.save_image);
        request.prepare(HttpRequest.Method.POST);
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(image, Base64.URL_SAFE);
        //image is a byte[] with image data
        HashMap<String, String>map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("username",username);
        map.put("image", encodedImage);
        Log.d("IMAGE-DATA", encodedImage);

        request.withData(map);
        JSONObject object = request.sendAndReadJSON();
        
        code = object.getInt("response_code");
        if (code == 0)
            flag = Boolean.FALSE;
        String s = object.getString("response_message");
        Log.d("SERVER-REPLY", s);
        //encodedImage and s are different
```

and the PHP code below:

```
<?php
  if(!$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
     $response["response_code"] = 0;
     $response["response_message"] = "INVALID REQUEST";
     die(json_encode($response));
  }
 if (empty($_POST)) {
    $response["response_code"] = 0;
    $response["response_message"] = "One or both of the fields are empty .";
    die(json_encode($response));
 }

$username1 = urldecode($_POST['username']); 
$data = $_POST['image'];
$binary = base64_decode($data);

list($path, $tmp) = explode(".", $username1);

$success = file_put_contents("./images/$path.png", $binary);
if ($success){
    $response["response_message"]=$data;
    $response["response_code"] = 1;
}else{
    $response["response_message"]="failure";
    $response["response_code"] = 0;
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Look into the differences. Sometimes you need to replace spaces with plusses. `$binary = base64_decode(str_replace(" ", "+", $_POST['image']));`.

Comment: Awesome that did the trick!!! Thanks @MarkusZeller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the differences. Sometimes you need to replace spaces with plusses.

```
$binary = base64_decode(str_replace(" ", "+", $_POST['image']));
```